# View in your space option missing in Realme X2 for google scene viewer

Tags: arcore, sceneview, oppo

I recently got the Realme X2 by Oppo  and tried out using the AR funtionalities with google scene viewer .
I do get the view in 3d option by searching animals like dog , cat , shark etc. , however I am not getting "view in your space" option. I read somewhere that we need play services for ar to be installed for this option to be available and in my case i do have it installed yet I am not getting this option.
Also just to clarify, google has listed realme x2 as supported device for ar services.
Any insight on this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with an outdated version of Google Play Services for AR. You can manually update it from play store. Also, if it does not solve the issue, try updating the Google app as well from play store.

Google Play Services for AR: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core

Google App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox